# Why wouldn't the head change - linkedlist implementation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linked-list

What I'm trying to do is to insert a node with a value to the ith location of a linked list. It has to return true if the insertion was successful, false otherwise. What I'm not able to understand is how to add to the start of the list. What I tries did not insert it at all. Where is the problem?

```
bool insertat(struct Node*head, int value,int loc){
    Node *q = new Node;     
    q->data=value;
    if(loc>list_length(head)){
        insertlast(head,value);
        return true;
    }
    else if(loc<=0){
        cout<<"invalid location";
        return false;
    }

    else if(loc==1){
        q->next=head;
        head=q;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        int i=1;
        Node*p =head;
        while( i<loc-1){
            p=p->next;
            i++;
        }
        q->next=p->next;
        p->next=q;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `bool insertat(struct Node*&head, int value,int loc){` (Note the reference `&`!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are passing pointer by value. So, changes done to head in this function are lost.

Rather change your function to:-

```
bool insertat(struct Node**head, int value,int loc)
```

and pass the address of head.

OR

```
bool insertat(struct Node*&head, int value,int loc)
```

Comment: Why not simply a reference? (and no need to change the current code)